# MVC Simplemembership I cannot get the userID after logging a user in via OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, simplemembership

So I am in the process of implementing a Facebook login via MVC 4 simplemembership oAuth provider.

Registering and signing in the user has worked well. However after signing in a user using oAth, I am unable to get the UserId of the authenticated user. I can see that the UserId exists in the membership_oauth table and it relates to the UserId in the UserProfile table.

Normally I would fetch it using WebSecurity.CurrentUserId but there does not seem to be a method for getting this when using OAuthWebSecurity. When I try, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId I get "an instance of the object has not been instantiated", error.

Does anybody know how to get this information?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to get the userID in in a controller. Have you tried:

```
int currentUserId = (int) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

I can't tell you if this works with Facebook or not, but it works with Google Auth. for me.

You should also add `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` on top of controller class if you use another controller than AccountController.

Check this: [Get UserId (int) in new MVC4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180434/get-userid-int-in-new-mvc4-application)

**EDIT:**

Check this method [`int GetUserIdFromOAuth(string provider, string providerUserId)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider.getuseridfromoauth%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and try something like:

```
SimpleMembershipProvider provider = (SimpleMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider;
int id = provider.GetUserIdFromOAuth("you_know_the_provider", "you_can_get_the_provider_user_id")
```

Also, the guy in this question:

[OAuth and SimpleMembership - how to retrieve ProviderUserId from webpages_OAuthMembership table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813923/oauth-and-simplemembership-how-to-retrieve-provideruserid-from-webpages-oauthm)

is complaining about the opposite of your problem: he wants the ProviderUserKey but keeps getting the UserID instead.

Comment: Thanks. Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey; returns the username provided by facebook, I'm trying to get the UserId that links the membership_oauth table to the UserProfile table. It is an int.